# UnknownHost Exception if url contains http/https

Tags: android, unknown-host

I am getting unknownhost exception in the following code if the value contains http or https. But it gives result if the url begins with www.

```
InetAddress.getByName(value)
```

Why is it so?

Answer (score 1):

Because `http`(or `https`) is the protocol, and not part of the name.

`InetAddress.getByName(value)` works with names only, not URLs.

Comment: But then, why do we not get response if we hit api without http or https

Comment: When you communicate with a host, you need to know the protocol. However, the `InetAddress` class is only responsible for IP address handling including name resolution, it does not provide a means of communication with the host.

Comment: Is there any way to keep http/https dynamically?
I got a requirement that use https for registration and login but http for other APIs keeping the base url same! Any solution for this?